# Conflicting Types for C program

Tags: c

I am attempting to make a function that splits a sentence into an array of strings (being separated at each space). My current code looks as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    void splitString(char);
    char meow[] = "Hello my name is ****";
    splitString(meow);
    return 0;
}


void splitString(char theString[]) {
    char* word = strtok(theString, " ");
    
    while (word != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", word);
        word = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    
}
```

When I compile this code I get the following error:

```
main.c:19:6: error: conflicting types for ‘splitString’
 void splitString(char theString[]) {
      ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

I was wondering if anyone knew how I can fix this error as I am not completely sure.

Answer (score 1):

You forward-declare `splitString` as `void splitString(char)` when it should be `void splitStirng(char[])`. Move it before main and change it:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void splitString(char[]);

int main() {
    char meow[] = "Hello my name is ****";
    splitString(meow);
    return 0;
}


void splitString(char theString[]) {
    char* word = strtok(theString, " ");

    while (word != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", word);
        word = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

}
```

Also include `<string.h>` since you use `strtok`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Forward declaring a function inside main is weird; move that outside of `main`.
2. `char` and `char []` are not the same type; change your forward declaration to match the actual signature of `splitString`.

   ```
   void splitString(char theString[]);
   ```
3. You could avoid forward declaring the function entirely by just moving it above `main`.